# Form tag should belong to Bootstrap's form control class and Search Input field requires a glyphicon search Icon

Tags: bootstrap-4

Requirements
Create a search input field in the navigation bar using Bootstrap input group component.
a.Create a form and align to right side of the navigation bar and form tag should contain  belongs to input group of Bootstrap class.
b. The input field belongs to the form control should have the placeholder "Search".
c. Create a span tag to group the input field button for the input search field.
d. Create a Bootstrap default button to display the glyphicon-search icon on it. This button should be the child of a span belongs to the Bootstrap input-group button.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Upon running the code I get the following errors:

1. Form tag should belong to Bootstrap's form control class
2. Search Input field requires a glyphicon search icon

Can you please help me with this??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OMG you still use BS3. It is now already BS5. I expect maybe this is for your assignment. Your teacher may need to update the teaching material :)

Full solution to your question is here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp
Scroll down to section for search form in the navbar for full code.

If my answer helps, please tick it as final answer and upvote it so other people with same problem will get help too. Cheers

Comment: I cannot resolve the errors. One last error I still face is "Form tag should belong to Bootstrap's form control class" and I don't know what it means in the above code's context.

Comment: Hi class "form-control" applies to all <input>, <select> tags . <form> tag is the most outer tag, see the code I reproduce in below for these tags placement

Comment: Yes, but I keep getting the same error. Can you just put on a correct code here? Would be great.

Comment: As I explained, <form> tag is the parent of all, the most outer tag. Its sub class .form-control and every other form elements, attributes and classes must be within <form> tag. That error has no logic. The logic is "Bootstrap's form control class should belong to Form tag " not the opposite way. Check it with your teacher/boss

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to resolve this error for quite some time now. It didn't make sense to me as well.

Comment: Agree hahaa. I developed tons of works using BS so you can be sure that smt odd with that error. Also I doubled check and just test your code. Your search box functions well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to show the placement and order of appearance of  => .form-control

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I get the code but my question is how to resolve the error "Form tag should belong to Bootstrap's form control class"? Please put on a correct code for the code I posted in the question itself.

Comment: As I explained, <form> tag is the parent of all, the most outer tag. Its sub class .form-control and every other form elements, attributes and classes must be within <form> tag. That error has no logic. The logic is "Bootstrap's form control class should belong to Form tag " not the opposite way. Check it with your teacher/boss

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting actually makes no sense, but after changing your input type="text" to type="search"(in below code line-3) will get the desired outcome without any errors.

```
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">                         
        <div class="input-group" >                
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn ">                   
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>                
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `.form-control` class inside the input field would solve the error.

[image]